# What are the differences between the original Hexcells, Pro, and Infinite?

Tags: version-differences, hexcells-infinite, hexcells

What are the differences between the original Hexcells and its sequels, Hexcells Pro and Hexcells Infinite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Forums](https://www.reddit.com/r/hexcells/comments/4mj6wt/difference_between_hexcells_plus_and_infinite/) report that the puzzles in the later editions are progressively harder than their predecessors.

**[Hexcells Plus](http://store.steampowered.com/app/271900/)** (Feb 2014) adds 36 puzzles.

**[Hexcells Infinite](http://store.steampowered.com/app/304410)** (Sept 2014) adds 36 puzzles, a random puzzle generator (each puzzle has a number and can be shared), mid-level saves, cross-platform cloud saves, and the ability to load custom user-made levels.